# How to catch wrong username or password on Expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I have a POST route that takes an username and password and returns a token on successful login. If either username or password are blank, it returns an error. However, if I provide a wrong username or password, I'm still getting a token generated from the provided information. How can I check the information returned from the database to return the same wrong username or password error? This is my route:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.username == '' || req.body.password == '') {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Wrong username or password" });
    } else {
        queries.login(req.body.username, req.body.password).then((user) => {
            if (res.error) {
                res.status(401).send({ error: 'Wrong username or password' });
            }
            res.json(auth.getToken(user.id, user.username));
        });
    }
});
```

And this is my query:

```
    async login(username, password) {
        let getUser = await knex('users').where('username', username);
        let user = getUser[0];

        try {
            if (await argon.verify(user.password_hash, password)) {
                return user;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login query you need to throw an error for the error case, like:

```js
async login(username, password) {
    try {
        let getUser = await knex('users').where('username', username);
        let user = getUser[0];

        if (await argon.verify(user.password_hash, password)) {
            return user;
        }

        throw Error('User not verified');
    } catch (e) {
        throw Error(e.message);
    }
}
```

Then in your route you can handle the error case by using `.catch()`:

```js
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.username == '' || req.body.password == '') {
        res.status(401).send({ error: "Wrong username or password" });
    } else {
        queries.login(req.body.username, req.body.password)
            .then((user) => {
                res.json(auth.getToken(user.id, user.username));
            });
            .catch((error) => {
                res.status(401).send({ error: 'Wrong username or password' });
            });
    }
});
```